How do I determine the stability of an equilibrium solution to a differential equation?
According to the notes issued out by my class, "an equilibrium solution $N (t) ≡ c$ to a differential equation (DE) is stable if $N(t)$ stays close to $c$ whenever $N(t)$ is a solution to the same DE such that $N(0)$ is sufficiently close to $c$."
What does this mean? I'm unsure as to how to apply it to math problems.
E.g., for the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=\cos(y)$ in the range $0<y<2\pi$, the equilibrium solutions are $y=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $y=\frac{3\pi}{2}$. According to the lecture notes, $y=\frac{\pi}{2}$ is a stable equilibrium solution and $y=\frac{3\pi}{2}$ is an unstable equilibrium solution. But how am I supposed to find this out?

It is easier to use the notation $dx/dt=f(x)$ and consider the solution $x(t)$ as the motion of a point on the $x$ axis.
The stability is rather easy, given $x_0$ an equilibrium solution

$f'(x_0)<0$, the equilibrium in stable
$f'(x_0)>0$, the equilibrium in unstable
$f'(x_0)=0$, a further analysis is needed

This is because if $f'(x_0)<0$, then $f(x)$ is negative to the right of $x_0$ and positive to the left, and the same holds for $dx/dt$ (given that $dx/dt=f(x)$), then if the point is on the right its velocity is directed to the left, i.e. toward $x_0$, and if the point is on the left its velocity is directed to the right, again toward $x_0$.
The revers happens if $f'(x_0)>0$.

In this case $y'(\frac{\pi}{2})=0$ and $y'(\frac{3\pi}{2})=0$. So how do do this 'further analysis'?

No, $f(x)=\cos x$, then $f'(x)=-\sin x$ and $f'(\pi/2) = -\sin\pi/2 = -1<0$, while $-\sin3\pi/2 = +1$
